# Django Bootstrap Carousel 4 items at a time

Tags: django, bootstrap-carousel

Good day SO.

I want to use Bootstrap Carousel with Django and display 4 items per `carousel-item`. (With a maximum of 20 items)

First on my views, I have created a view:

```
items = AllItems.objects.all().order_by('-id')
context['items'] = items
```

Next, on my template I believe I need to loop through my items like this

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for item in items%}
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 == 1 or forloop.first %} // Add the opening div
            <div class="carousel-item"> 
        {% endif %}
            <div class="item">{{item.item_title}}</div>              // Add the items
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 == 0 or forloop.last %}  // Add the closing div
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

But reality is different. Hoping to ask your logic on this type of scenario.

Do I need to use paginator for this? Though my second option was to use paginator, then use ajax and jquery to create div per carousel-item.

Comment: @Sumithran. It got me started. After a few tweaks, it is now rendering like I want. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#slice)

```
<ul>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for item in items|slice:":4"%} <!-- Shows first four objects -->
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
        <div class="item">{{item.item_title}}</div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: This got me started on what I needed. Thank you